# Swiper slider c полосой прокрутки и прогресс-баром

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swiper

Допилила прогресс-бар для прокрутки. Но работает он кривовато. При прокрутке иногда появляется такое. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите в какую сторону посмотреть, чтоб это исправить. Или может есть к-нибудь событие, чтобы можно отслеживать изменение в css элемента

```
код
```

Посмотреть код можно [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/semenova_7oa/33gz6qh7/)

Comment: проблема заключается в том, что стили линии меняются уже в тот момент, когда круг достигает конечной точки, а сам круг анимируется через transtiion по ходу.

Comment: это да. непонятно как это решить

Comment: в общем решила проблему версткой